# How to set an index of an array within a struct as a variable(Coldfusion)

Tags: arrays, coldfusion

This is the first error that I am getting:
Invalid data [d6-2014-74, , ] for CFSQLTYPE CF_SQL_VARCHAR

Here is the corresponding code.

```
 <cfset x = Arguments.surveyDocNo>
 <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#x#">
```

[image: First Error Image:]

To solve that problem, I changed my code to this:

```
 <cfset x = Arguments.surveyDocNo[1]>
```

However, that returns this error:

500 You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class java.lang.String as a structure with members.

[image: Error 2]

So the array issue is fixed, but I don't know how to fix the second error.

```
 <cfdump var="#arguments.surveyDocNo#">
```

[image]

Comment: In your first screen shot `surveyDocNo` is an Array but in your second screenshot it is a string. If you changed the variable to no longer be an array then you can go back to your original reference `Arguments.surveyDocNo` without the index value.

Comment: @Miguel-F Thanks for the quick response. Maybe I'm not understanding correctly, but when I go back to my original reference, it becomes an array again.

Comment: To avoid confusion, can you please dump the `Arguments.surveyDocNo` variable (not the whole structure) and post a screen shot.

Comment: @Leigh I added the information you requested.

Comment: Thanks. It clearly is an array, so I do not see how `<cfset x = Arguments.surveyDocNo[1]>` could possibly throw the error *"...attempted to dereference a scalar variable"*.  Seems like either different code is causing that error OR there is something more going on that we are aware of ...?

Comment: Can you put together a small repro case? A *stand alone* example that demonstrates the issue, example: http://trycf.com/gist/797d66bead3e8c4c56a5e91bc24f80b7/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: Could you do a `<cfdump var="#arguments.surveyDocNo[1]#">`

Answer (score 4):

I assume you pass the `surveyDocNo` argument sometimes as string and sometimes as an array of strings.

```
<!--- if argument is passed as array, take the first element --->
<cfif isArray(Arguments.surveyDocNo) and (not arrayIsEmpty(Arguments.surveyDocNo))>
    <cfset x = Arguments.surveyDocNo[1]>
<cfelse>
    <cfset x = Arguments.surveyDocNo>
</cfif>

<!--- if the provided argument is not a string, throw an exception --->
<cfif not isSimpleValue(x)>
    <cfthrow type="IllegalArgumentException" message="The provided value for argument [surveyDocNo] is invalid. Expected a string.">
</cfif>

<cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#x#">
```